# Excelformula to assign ticket numbers

Tags: google-sheets

Each participants gets X numbers of tickets. The number of tickets can change dynamically by day. I need help with the formula to fetch the ticket numbers each participants get.

Right now the columns for Ticket numbers are:

=IF(B2 > 0, D1+1,D1)

=C2+B2

This isn't quite right for obvious reasons.

[image]

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOqPXjtF1CqWg22z5z_XxhNv7CKuH12_JmuQHhLtdk8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this excel or google-sheets? Please adjust your tags. As we can't see your column headers it is hard to judge why sth doesn't work ... moreover to me it is not "obvious" what isn't right ...

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I've edited my post to include an example and the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you require?

```
=IFS(ISTEXT(B1),1,A2=0,0,B1=0,SUM(A1:A$2),TRUE,C1+1)

=IFS(A2=0,0,A2=1,B2,TRUE,B2+A2-1)
```

[image: Formula with sample data]